# How to group by one column and limit to rows where another column has the same value for all rows in group?

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE userinteractions
(
userid  bigint,
dobyr int,
-- lots more fields that are not relevant to the question
);
```

My problem is that some of the data is polluted with multiple `dobyr` values for the same user.

The table is used as the basis for further processing by creating a new table. These cases need to be removed from the pipeline.

I want to be able to create a clean table that contains unique `userid` and `dobyr` limited to the cases where there is only one value of `dobyr` for the `userid` in `userinteractions`.

For example I start with data like this:

```
userid,dobyr
1,1995
1,1995
2,1999
3,1990 # dobyr values not equal
3,1999 # dobyr values not equal
4,1989
4,1989
```

And I want to select from this to get a table like this:

```
userid,dobyr
1,1995
2,1999
4,1989
```

Is there an elegant, efficient way to get this in a single sql query?

I am using postgres.

EDIT: I do not have permissions to modify the `userinteractions` table, so I need a `SELECT` solution, not a `DELETE` solution.

Comment: [`delete from userinteractions where ctid not in (select min(ctid) from userinteractions group by userid,dobyr);`](https://dbfiddle.uk/68kmFWwn)

Comment: interesting approach. i cannot delete the original tables though, i do not have permissions. can the same logic be done as a `select`? i reworded the question to be more clear.

Comment: So what is the rule to select one specific `dobyr` if there are multiple?

Comment: Generally, every delete command can be converted to a query and vice versa. Just change "delete" to "select columnSelection" and back again without changing the rest.

Comment: @mmdanziger [`create table userinteractions_deduplicated as select * from userinteractions where ctid in (select min(ctid) from userinteractions group by userid,dobyr);`](https://dbfiddle.uk/SHf1UGhR) You could also apply a proper [unique](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) constraint to the new table to prevent new dupes from flowing in. If you don't want to lose the incoming non-unique rejected records, you can set up a separate *_rejects* table and route them there using a trigger or a rule.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name there is no rule, the records are judged to be polluted and filtered out from the new table create

Comment: I think it's about a situation where you find two `(userid,dobyr,something)` records `(1,2,'a')` and `(1,2,'b')` - which one do you wish to keep?

Comment: oh wow, nice use of `ctid` i've never seen that before. it looks like that would work. can you expand it as an answer? i'll test it on my end and accept

Comment: oh, i see. that logic is already defined for each column individually in the code. there are mins, maxes etc. i didn't include it in the question because i'm assuming it won't make a difference and i don't want to clutter it with unrelated details.

Answer (score 1):

Clarified requirements: your aim is to generate a new, cleaned-up version of an existing table, and the clean-up means:

1. If there are many rows with the same `userid` value but also the same `dobyr` value, one of them is kept (doesn't matter which one), rest gets discarded.
2. All rows for a given `userid` are discarded if it occurs with different `dobyr` values.

```sql
create table userinteractions_clean as 
select distinct on (userid,dobyr) * 
from userinteractions
where userid in ( 
    select   userid
    from     userinteractions
    group by userid
    having   count(distinct dobyr)=1 )
order by userid,dobyr;
```

This could also be done with an `not in`, `not exists` or `exists` conditions. Also, select which combination to keep by adding columns at the end of `order by`.
[Updated demo with tests and more rows.](https://dbfiddle.uk/XLO5BO5p?hide=256)

If you don't need the other columns in the table, only something you'll later use as a filter/whitelist, plain `userid`'s from records with `(userid,dobyr)` pairs matching your criteria are enough, as they already uniquely identify those records:

```sql
create table userinteractions_whitelist as
select   userid
from     userinteractions
group by userid
having   count(distinct dobyr)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a HAVING clause to assert that all rows in a group must have the same dobyr.

```
SELECT
  userid,
  MAX(dobyr) AS dobyr
FROM
  userinteractions
GROUP BY
  userid
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT dobyr) = 1
```

Comment: What about the *`-- lots more fields`* part? As far as I understand, the query is supposed to produce a table with *all* the fields of `userinteractions`, which is why I nested this and used a `distinct on` outside. This takes only these two fields.

Comment: @Zegarek That's not how I read the OP. The example specifically shows collapsing multiple rows to a single row, which makes no sense if other Columns are involved. The additional columns are also commented as being not relevant, and don't appear on the expected results.